# How to access class properties from parent abstract class to a static method?

Tags: php, oop

Here is a simple example.

```
abstract class A{
  protected $foo = 'I m foo'; 
}

class B extends A{
  static function sayFoo(){
     // get the value of $foo here. 
  }
}
```

I can pass foo as a constant, or change the function from static to normal, or declare `sayFoo` inside the parent class but I want to check if there is another way first without using Reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `protected $foo` property statically because it isn't declared static.  However you could if it was an object.  One way to go about this is instantiate the class inside of your static function.

```
<?php

abstract class A{
  protected $foo = 'I m foo'; 
}

class B extends A{
  static function sayFoo(){
     // get the value of $foo here. 
      $bar = new self();
      echo $bar->foo;
  }
}   

B::sayFoo(); //prints 'I m foo';

?>
```

Comment: I still don't understand the `new self()`s role in this.

Comment: @BiVOC `self` is a reference to the current class name.  Consider it the same as having done `$bar = new B()`;